# Read templates from a file StringTemplate

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

I'm using the template engine StringTemplate for some templates (obviously).

What I want is to be able to store the templates I have in seperate files, ofcourse I can do that with simple .txt files and reading them into a `String`, looks a bit like this then

```
ST template = new ST(readTemplateFromFile("template.txt"))

private String readTemplateFromFile(String templateFile){
//read template from file
}
```

But what I was wondering is if there's functionality in the StringTemplate engine to do that automatically. SO that i don't have to write code that already exists.

I've read something about Group Files but I don't quite understand that,are those like Template files? Or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Well, you could do `return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(templateFile)), StandardCharSets.UTF_8)`. For example. But I would generally assume that your templates would be on the classpath rather than in a file.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the question is not how to read the file but if there's functionality in the STringTemplate engine to store templates in files and read them fron files

Comment: Here is an example for `stringtemplate v3`: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is functionality available that can be used directly without providing your own file loading code.

From the [ST JavaDoc](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/ST.html):

> To use templates, you create one (usually via [STGroup](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/STGroup.html)) and then inject attributes using [add(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/ST.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). To render its attacks, use [render()](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/org/stringtemplate/v4/ST.html#render--).

To follow that advice the following code can be used.

First, create a file called `exampleTemplate.stg` and place it on your classpath.

```
templateExample(param) ::= <<
This is a template with the following param: (<param>)
>>
```

Then, render the template by using the following code:

```
// Load the file
final STGroup stGroup = new STGroupFile("exampleTemplate.stg");

// Pick the correct template
final ST templateExample = stGroup.getInstanceOf("templateExample");

// Pass on values to use when rendering
templateExample.add("param", "Hello World");

// Render
final String render = templateExample.render();

// Print
System.out.println(render);
```

The output is:

> This is a template with the following param: (Hello World)

---

Some additional notes:

- `STGroupFile` is a subclass of `STGroup`. There are other subclasses as well that you find out more about in the [JavaDoc](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api/).
- In the example above the template file was placed on the classpath. This is not a requirement, files can be placed in a relative folder or a in an absolute folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than the interpolation found in other languagues such as Python's f-strings.  For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```